# YouTube Live Streaming API 'scheduledStartTime' Displaying Wrong Timezone to Viewers

Tags: javascript, datetime, youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

When creating a new live event with the YouTube API I am having this problem. Despite passing the correct ISO 8601 date format, the timezone that is displayed to all viewers in GMT -7, not their local timezone. Here are the details:

I am working in JavaScript and making the following call:

```
gapi.client.youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert(
    {
      'part': 'snippet,status',
      'snippet': 
        {
          'title': $("#title").val(),
          'scheduledStartTime': moment($('#datetime').data("DateTimePicker").date().format()).format(), // using datepicker and moment.js - looks like: 2017-10-31T16:02:05Z
          'description': $("#description").val() // optional
        }, 
          'status': {'privacyStatus': ($('input[name=privacy]:checked').val() == 'private') ? 'unlisted' : 'public' }
        }


     ).then(function(response){ 
...
```

Here is the documentation which states the kind of datestring that is required:

> The date and time that the broadcast is scheduled to start. The value is specified in ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.scheduledStartTime

This is an example of a datestring I am passing, note the -04:00 for a US/Eastern Time Zone:

```
"2017-10-31T16:02:05Z"
```

Despite that, YouTube creates the event at the right time but displays the  event in GMT-7, not the local timezone (I am EST) (see screen shot):
[image: screen shot of GMT-7 issue]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or is this a possible bug in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had submitted this question to the YouTube Partners API support.  I never heard back but I have noticed that now events flash between displaying in PST and Local time.  On the YouTube dashboard, the event also is stated in PST but it's nice to see local time on the "watch" page.

I don't know if my question contributed to this fix, but the behavior solves the problem I was having.

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the same issue.
I think it always use the pacific time zone.
The only workaround i think it's to translate the scheduled time to pacific time zone. For example subtracting 8 hours to the scheduled time.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) This answer does not meet the need of the OP. Instead, this is more of a comment rather than an answer.